# How to connect an old library to the last Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I want to use the old library
https://github.com/ksksue/PhysicaloidLibrary

in the last Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 Patch 2 (full Android Studio info is below)
But the old recommendations 'How to use' don't work.

1.**Please, help me to connect this library https://github.com/ksksue/PhysicaloidLibrary
to new Android Studio.**

2.Where is placed the full information, how to change the old advices to connect modules, libraries to the new Android Studio projects? For example, about change key words 'compile' to 'implementation' in gradle.build and others or repository use, or what must be change when updating gradle and SDK versions, etc. I'd say, some article|blog about software updating when Android Studio is updated.

Best regards,
Vadim

---

What was made.
I downloaded the GitHub's lib to PC:
https://github.com/ksksue/PhysicaloidLibrary.git
then tried 'How to use':

1. File -> import and select a PhysicaloidLibrary directory.
   This was made successfully
2. Right click your project -> Properties -> Android -> click Library's "Add" button -> select PhysicaloidLibrary

I can't find this "Add" button or something as it.
I also tried the example project 'PhysicaloidTest' from the lib archive: The build shows a number of errors and the app tree is fully different from the trees in new projects.
The Import of this project also gives the error.

The Android is new for me, and there are difficulties to repeat the 1- 10-years old examples or use some libs from android-arsenal.com.

---

'About' copy:
Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 Patch 2
Build #AI-231.9392.1.2311.11330709, built on January 19, 2024
Runtime version: 17.0.7+0-b2043.56-10550314 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 10.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 4
Registry:
external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
ide.text.editor.with.preview.show.floating.toolbar=false

Comment: The first important detail is that those old projects require Java/JDK 8 to be executed (requires JAVA_HOME env variable to be set). Unfortunately the developer who created this project had not used the gradle wrapper system which automatically downloads the appropriate gradle version and uses it. Otherwise you could have simply compiled the library on command-line using `./gradlew assemble` - but because of the missing gradle wrapper you can only try to manually download gradle versions of that time and try to build the project by `<path to gradle>/gradle assemble` or a different task name.

Comment: How to implement in new Android Studio the 2nd item: <2.Right click your project -> Properties -> Android -> click Library's "Add" button -> select PhysicaloidLibrary>? Where the 'Add' button is placed now? What is it 'Right click the project? 'app' in the project tree has not the 'Properties' item, this is true also for <Project name> in left top corner....